# Extending the student applicant visa outside of Germany

Tags: germany, student-visa

I am student interested in studying in Germany, and I have applied for a few universities. To be allowed into the universities, I need to a do a prepartory course known as studienkolleg which has an entrance exam. **The problem is, some of the entrance exam I applied for are spaced further than three months apart (the typical duration of student visa).**

Looking up on how to renew the student visa, I find it that I need to be inside Germany with residence, and an enrollment to a university to do it ([source](https://www.study-in-germany.de/en/community/extending-the-student-visa/)). This is an issue for me as I don't **plan on staying in Germany in the gap period between the exams**, and I would **need to actually pass the exams to get an enrollment**.

**Would I be able to extend my student visa on the basis of needing more time to write all the exams I need time for?**

---

A possible solution I found is to take a tourist visa to write the first few exams, and then national visa on basis of success in the first few exams/ on needing to write the later exams. If I could do the exams consecutively on a single national visa, it'd be a lot less work to me, so I search better solutions still.