# Would taking student applicant visa require more time than tourist visa?

Tags: germany

The context is, I am an Indian living in Kuwait. Due to some schedule difficulties as I have already [described here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26268/extending-the-student-applicant-visa-outside-of-germany), I would need to get a visa quickly. As far as I know, I am eligible in terms of raw requirements for both a tourist visa and a student visa. My question is, which would be processed faster?

Common sense tells me it would be tourist, but it seems here that tourist visa appointment slots are more often booked than Student applicant visa/ national visa appointment slots.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with German visas, but student visas are usually processed faster. More appointment slots will be available, and some countries like the US have an option for an emergency visa application in case your course is going to start soon. Processing is also usually faster. Tourist visas aren't given as much importance because they're assumed to be for recreation, as opposed to education or work.

Comment: The mere question is ludicrous. German bureaucracy is slooow. You need to apply _as soon as possible_. Do not hesitate and ponder which option might be faster. A difference of a couple days is _irrelevant_ if either application takes, say, three months.